# Delete row which contains foreign key dont display any result in SQL

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have table in SQL called `address` which has columns

```
id, subid, country, state, city
```

Each region saved in row which subid contain the id of its parent.

I joined this row as follow:

```
SELECT  
    [Address].country AS Parent, p.country AS state,
    c.country AS city, h.country AS hamlet
FROM 
    [Address] p  
LEFT JOIN
    [Address] ON p.subid = [Address].id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    [Address] c ON c.subid = p.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    [Address] h ON h.subid = c.id
```

But when delete any region no results are displayed. Can anyone help me please?

Deletion Query:

```
delete from address where country = '" & TreeView1.SelectedNode.Text.ToString & "' and tag='country
```

Comment: Can you please share your delete query?

Comment: delete from address where country = '" & TreeView1.SelectedNode.Text.ToString & "' and tag='country

Comment: You don't use parameters? That's evil...

Comment: Delete row from where? What results are you expecting from a delete?

Comment: Would it be possible to include a snippet of data so we can infer the relationships ourselves as well as the schema for the Address table.